# Is the difference between 'significant' and 'not-significant' significant?

Tags: r, glm, significance

My sample includes 744 subjects, of which 175 belong to group `L == 0`, while the other 569 to group `L == 1` (please see data below).

I used GLM for a binary outcome to test for group differences in background variables -

```
summary(
  pre <- glm(L ~ g + a + m + p + e, 
                       family = binomial("logit"), 
                       data = df))
```

...yielding significant differences for 5 of them: g, a, m, p, and e).

So I modeled these 5 background variables as covariates when testing for an association between my predictor, `chr` and my outcome `rsk`, in each one of the groups (`L == 0`, `L == 1`), again using GLM for binary outcome:

```
summary(
  fit <- glm(rsk ~ chr + g + a + m + p + e, 
             family = binomial("logit"), 
             data = df[which(df$L == 0), ]))


summary(
  fit <- glm(rsk ~ chr + g + a + m + p + e, 
             family = binomial("logit"), 
             data = df[which(df$L == 1), ]))
```

The results showed that a significant association does exist for `L == 0` but not for `L == 1`.

I would appreciate your help in **how to test whether significance/non-significance can be attributed to the group condition?**. Or in other words, how to test for significance of the difference between groups with regard to the correlation chr-rsk?

Thanks for respondents!

Uri

```
structure(list(L = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), g = c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), a = c(38L, 36L, 33L, 34L, 44L, 38L, 
23L, 37L, 37L, 28L, 25L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 32L, 34L, 34L, 29L, 37L, 
32L, 37L, 37L, 32L, 34L, 39L, 33L, 35L, 34L, 32L, 36L, 30L, 39L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 32L, 40L, 34L, 37L, 37L, 34L, 38L, 36L, 43L, 31L, 
37L, 32L, 31L, 42L, 31L, 31L, 34L, 39L, 32L, 36L, 30L, 47L, 34L, 
32L, 34L, 37L, 35L, 38L, 35L, 34L, 31L, 39L, 34L, 34L, 33L, 44L, 
35L, 33L, 34L, 31L, 37L, 35L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 34L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 
33L, 34L, 40L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 35L, 28L, 33L, 36L, 35L, 38L, 
34L, 36L, 33L, 32L, 37L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 30L, 33L, 31L, 35L, 38L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 39L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 
37L, 29L, 36L, 39L, 29L, 34L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 39L, 34L, 36L, 44L, 
34L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 38L, 43L, 38L, 39L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 32L, 33L, 
37L, 32L, 35L, 34L, 29L, 33L, 39L, 35L, 43L, 37L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 
39L, 31L, 37L, 31L, 34L, 35L, 39L, 33L, 34L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 36L, 
37L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 39L, 33L, 36L, 43L, 41L, 30L, 33L, 43L, 32L, 
40L, 48L, 32L, 37L, 32L, 38L, 34L, 38L, 37L, 33L, 32L, 42L, 37L, 
41L, 37L, 31L, 34L, 33L, 36L, 30L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 32L, 
39L, 31L, 39L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 39L, 31L, 34L, 33L, 41L, 29L, 41L, 
39L, 31L, 30L, 36L, 32L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 32L, 40L, 37L, 38L, 37L, 
33L, 32L, 34L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 38L, 34L, 38L, 33L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 42L, 36L, 32L, 36L, 39L, 33L, 36L, 30L, 36L, 35L, 
40L, 37L, 34L, 40L, 36L, 34L, 38L, 35L, 35L, 31L, 34L, 38L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 37L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 29L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 38L, 32L, 
30L, 35L, 27L, 33L, 36L, 36L, 34L, 31L, 34L, 31L, 37L, 34L, 34L, 
47L, 30L, 45L, 33L, 30L, 36L, 32L, 34L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 37L, 32L, 
25L, 35L, 40L, 32L, 33L, 38L, 31L, 30L, 43L, 30L, 41L, 32L, 33L, 
35L, 35L, 33L, 35L, 40L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 38L, 37L, 38L, 33L, 32L, 
34L, 34L, 43L, 31L, 31L, 35L, 34L, 31L, 41L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 39L, 
36L, 33L, 31L, 30L, 37L, 37L, 33L, 30L, 36L, 36L, 41L, 43L, 38L, 
44L, 32L, 30L, 35L, 34L, 31L, 43L, 49L, 32L, 40L, 40L, 42L, 46L, 
40L, 30L, 34L, 32L, 23L, 38L, 42L, 41L, 41L, 30L, 34L, 34L, 32L, 
33L, 35L, 36L, 42L, 36L, 30L, 33L, 41L, 31L, 37L, 28L, 34L, 32L, 
37L, 31L, 33L, 39L, 37L, 35L, 37L, 37L, 34L, 32L, 36L, 36L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 33L, 37L, 40L, 36L, 34L, 38L, 34L, 36L, 45L, 32L, 38L, 
36L, 38L, 40L, 46L, 38L, 34L, 40L, 43L, 38L, 35L, 39L, 29L, 41L, 
37L, 38L, 33L, 40L, 40L, 36L, 40L, 39L, 38L, 31L, 36L, 36L, 32L, 
34L, 39L, 49L, 46L, 33L, 42L, 33L, 58L, 28L, 30L, 35L, 35L, 32L, 
38L, 41L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 38L, 41L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 30L, 
31L, 33L, 31L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 37L, 43L, 43L, 26L, 35L, 30L, 
34L, 38L, 31L, 31L, 30L, 35L, 46L, 33L, 37L, 33L, 47L, 34L, 31L, 
35L, 30L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 40L, 32L, 29L, 27L, 40L, 36L, 41L, 
38L, 43L, 35L, 30L, 38L, 35L, 38L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 33L, 
36L, 38L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 38L, 32L, 40L, 41L, 32L, 38L, 31L, 34L, 
35L, 35L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 38L, 34L, 35L, 33L, 37L, 36L, 33L, 31L, 
31L, 33L, 34L, 41L, 47L, 35L, 35L, 43L, 37L, 35L, 34L, 32L, 41L, 
34L, 29L, 21L, 28L, 32L, 35L, 33L, 39L, 39L, 36L, 22L, 31L, 41L, 
38L, 37L, 39L, 36L, 29L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 24L, 35L, 40L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 33L, 41L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 35L, 30L, 43L, 31L, 32L, 38L, 
30L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 35L, 48L, 33L, 39L, 33L, 38L, 34L, 27L, 33L, 
34L, 32L, 33L, 39L, 35L, 43L, 40L, 34L, 39L, 33L, 35L, 42L, 36L, 
37L, 37L, 44L, 36L, 38L, 34L, 32L, 41L, 46L, 39L, 35L, 34L, 36L, 
32L, 37L, 33L, 44L, 42L, 44L, 40L, 34L, 44L, 32L, 38L, 37L, 38L, 
32L, 43L, 36L, 29L, 35L, 36L, 31L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 45L, 45L, 41L, 
28L, 38L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 38L, 33L, 36L, 44L, 43L, 
36L, 38L, 31L, 31L, 36L, 33L, 34L, 25L, 35L, 37L, 42L, 31L, 33L, 
33L, 30L, 37L, 37L, 34L, 46L, 32L, 34L, 40L, 33L, 39L, 42L, 44L, 
42L, 35L, 42L, 35L, 41L, 31L, 27L, 23L, 32L, 42L, 42L, 33L, 40L, 
38L, 29L, 40L, 33L, 33L, 43L, 40L, 41L, 32L, 31L), m = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), p = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), e = c(6L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), chr = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 1L), rsk = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 
150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 
161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 
172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 
183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 
195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 
206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 
217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 
228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 
240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 
252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 
263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 
274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 
285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 
296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 
307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 
318L, 319L, 320L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 
330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 
341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 
352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 
364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 
375L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 
386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 
397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 
408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 
419L, 420L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 
431L, 432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 
442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 
453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 
464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 
475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 
486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 
497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 
508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 
519L, 520L, 521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 
530L, 531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 
541L, 542L, 543L, 544L, 545L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 549L, 550L, 551L, 
552L, 553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L, 561L, 562L, 
563L, 564L, 565L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 570L, 571L, 572L, 573L, 
574L, 575L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 579L, 580L, 581L, 582L, 583L, 585L, 
586L, 587L, 588L, 589L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 
597L, 598L, 599L, 600L, 601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 
608L, 609L, 610L, 611L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 617L, 618L, 
619L, 620L, 621L, 622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 
630L, 631L, 632L, 633L, 634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 
641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 
652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 662L, 
663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 
674L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 678L, 679L, 680L, 681L, 682L, 683L, 684L, 
685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 690L, 691L, 692L, 693L, 694L, 695L, 
696L, 697L, 698L, 699L, 701L, 702L, 703L, 704L, 705L, 706L, 707L, 
708L, 709L, 710L, 711L, 712L, 713L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 717L, 718L, 
719L, 720L, 721L, 722L, 723L, 724L, 725L, 726L, 727L, 728L, 729L, 
730L, 731L, 732L, 733L, 734L, 735L, 736L, 737L, 738L, 739L, 740L, 
741L, 742L, 743L, 744L, 745L, 746L, 747L, 748L, 749L, 750L, 751L, 
752L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: One way you might get at this is re-building your model such that `L` is the response variable, and `rsk` one of the predictors. This would let you ask questions about which variables (including `rsk` itself) are clearly associated with `L`. You might model the *interactions* between `rsk` and the other covariates in the new model to capture some of your original relationships too.

Comment: This might be a good Cross Validated question

Comment: Hi @Uri, is L categorical or continuous? Meaning is L groups 1-5 or is it a increasing value?

Comment: I was looking at your model and data, it seems categorical.

Comment: thanks, Michael and StupidWolf. L is binary. On the occasion, can you give explain why Cross Validated is better for this purpose?

Comment: Sorry I was referring to "chr". I see that it goes 1-5 and if get better fit as a factor.  I can write a solution for you. Is anyone of these a control, or reference group? You should fit everything into the model, to estimate the other background variables correctly.

Comment: You see that the background variates g,a,m,p,e are associated with L being 0 and 1. So might not be most accurate if you put them in one full model. If you make two models, and test against chr while controlling for these background variables, you see a significant association between chr and rsk in 0, but not 1

Comment: However, if you consider them separately you fail to account for the effect of L. if you do by(df[,c("chr","rsk")],df$L,colMeans), you can see that in group 0, rsk and chr is much lower to start with. If the association between chr and rsk is only valid in one group, there should not be this kind of segregation to start with

Comment: This is a rough understanding from a non-expert, but I think of Stack Overflow as the place for the technical/ programming related questions, but for statistical advice, Cross Validated is the place. It seems like your question is not "How do I fit this particular model I understand really well in R?" but instead "What kind of model would be appropriate for my question."

Comment: Thank you, both. Stupidwolf. I read your reply carefully. However, I am not sure whether the approach you suggested can affirm whether for a certain value of L the association chr-rsk is significant, but not for the other.